# Mathematical rounding in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, financial, calc

I there a built-in function for proper mathematical rounding in vb.net?

For example, both functions below return 14.00, but they should return 14.01:

```
Math.Round(14.004999, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
Decimal.Round(14.004999, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Are there any other methods that do proper mathematical rounding?

Comment: Why do you think that the answer should ever end with .01?  You are rounding to two decimals and the third decimal is 4.

Comment: If you're expecting it to always round up because of the `AwayFromZero`, note the name of the enum - `MidpointRounding`, it only applies to values that are exactly halfway - rounding otherwise works as usual

Comment: I'm not expecting to always round up.
But I am expecting that the whole number is taken into the account.
So in my example the nines would be carried over, so the entire rounding process would go something like this:
14.004999 -> 14.005 -> 14.01

I hope I made myself a bit cleared now :)

Comment: That's just not how rounding works.  `.004999` is less than `0.005` so it will get rounded down.

Comment: You are right. Guess I've had my head stuck in financial calculations too long and forgot how real math works :D

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the desired results, but...

```
Dim somedata As Double = 14.004999
Dim outd As Double

outd = Math.Round(somedata, 3)
outd = Math.Round(outd, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1/2 cent to the calculations:

```
Dim x As Decimal = 14.004999D

Dim y as Decimal = Decimal.Round(x + 0.005D, 2, System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Be sure to use the `Decimal` type and not the `Double` type in financial math.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is ceiling, not rounding.

```
Dim d As Decimal = 14.004999
Dim r As Decimal = Math.Ceiling(d * 100D) / 100D
```

Comment: `"Proper mathematical rounding"` **IS NOT** using ceiling. Ceiling will always round up, while proper mathematical rounding is for example: `0.5 -> 1` and `0.4 -> 0`. _Anything above **and including .5** will be rounded up, while everything **below .5** will be rounded down._

Comment: Correct me if i wrong: you say that 14.004999 should be rounded to 14.01, but .0049 is below .005, thus it rounded to 0 and you receive 14.00, if you want it to be 14.01 you only need to round it up. Where i'm wrong?

Comment: No I never said that. I said `0.5` should be rounded to `1` and `0.4` to `0`. It was two examples of the type of rounding _that he wants_. However ceiling always rounds up, meaning if his input is dynamic this won't do the trick.